# How do I use if else statements in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm from a python background and I'm finding it difficult to pick up the syntax in c#.

I'm trying to write code so that the program will continuously ask the user for input and it will echo it on the screen, but if the user input is 'exit' then it exits.

I tried

Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

```
        Console.Write("Enter some text:  ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userinput == "exit")
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userinput);
```

But it doesn't achieve expected results

Comment: "But it doesn't achieve expected results" - well what happened? That looks fine to me, apart from the lack of a curly brace...

Comment: @JonSkeet ...let alone the absence of a looping construct for continuously asking the user for input :-)

Comment: maybe useful:[so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223063/continuous-input-to-switch-case-until-i-press-exit-c-sharp)

Comment: ...how would being from a python background make you think an `if` statement should act as a loop?

Comment: SO is not a place to put code, and ask for code. A little search would have gave you what you want.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, I was assuming the looping was coming later :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement only executes once.

Since you're looking to take some action repeatedly, a `do/while` construct is more along the lines of what you need.

Something like this should at least get you started in the right direction:

```
string userinput;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter some text:  ");
    userinput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(userinput);
}
while (userinput != "exit");
```